# Does multiprocessing run on one core

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

I'm reading on multiprocessing with selenium to see its advantages over multithreading with selenium.

I understand computers have cores, e.g. mine has 4, and that computers have logical cores, e.g. mine has 4 also.

What I'm trying to understand is that when I use multiprocessing does do it all on one core, and if so which one? as in the main core being used by my computer or other cores.

Is it also possible to choose how many processes you want on a core, and should there be a limit.

**My Questions if not clear:**

1. Does multiprocessing happen all on one core
2. Can you choose how many processes you want on a core
3. Should there be a limit to how many processes you have on a core

   - If there should be a limit what is the best way to work this out

**Here's my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
import multiprocessing



class go():
    def __init__(self):
        self.run()
    def run(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless', )
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=options)
        self.browser.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')

        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchInput"))).send_keys('Python',Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)
        print('Moved To Next Section ')

        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Computing"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)
        print('Moved To Next Section ')

        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "People"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)

        print('Moved To Next Section ')
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Roller coasters"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)

        print('Moved To Next Section ')
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Vehicles"))).click()
        time.sleep(3)

        print('Moved To Next Section ')
        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Weaponry"))).click()
        time.sleep(100)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    for count in range(10):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=go).start()
```

Comment: There's no main core, all cores are equal.
Your code spawns processes, and the OS decides which process is handled by which core. (it's also possible it will switch cores)
Multiple processes can run on a single core, but then it's not really multiprocessing, as it will race for CPU resources.

Comment: so, are you saying that multiprocessing will automatically use some sort of intelligence to designate processes to cores

Comment: @coderoftheday no, `multiprocessing` simply spawns *multiple processes*. It's the operating system that decides which cores are used

Comment: I see, so would it be smart to use threads to do multi multiprocesses, to increase performance

Comment: Multi processing and multi threading are 2 different things.
Unless you want to do IO based operations (e.g. HTTP requests, Reading from Queues/DB), then multithreading is no use for you, as python doesn't have a true multi threading. (you should read about multi threading in python, and about the GIL- Global Interperter Lock)

Comment: @coderoftheday You don't use threads to create multiple processes, threads are for *multithreading*. In CPython, threading will *always* be limited to a single thread running at a time, due to the global interpreter lock, so CPU bound code will likely not be improved, but IO bound can.

Comment: thanks, i will do some more research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does multiprocessing happen all on one core

No

> Can you choose how many processes you want on a core

No

> Should there be a limit to how many processes you have on a core
> If there should be a limit what is the best way to work this out

This is not something you do from python code. O/S is in charge of it. For user there is virtually no limit on number of threads or processes.

And Meny Issakov is right, you should read on multiprocessing in python.